# react datepicker getting jumbled when displaying

Tags: react-datepicker

[image]

react datepicker calendar getting jumbled as shown in pic. works in one component but gets jumbled in any others. the one that works in previously integrated

```
<DatePicker
              className="w-64 text-primary-black"
              selected={startDate}
              onChange={onChange}
              startDate={startDate}
              endDate={endDate}
              selectsRange
              showMonthDropdown
              showYearDropdown
              open={true}
              useShortMonthInDropdown
              customInput={<DateInput />}
              dropdownMode="select"
              dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
              isClearable
            />
```